# Using field from another table in popup of ArcGIS Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder, infowindow

I have an Web AppBuilder application, in popup windows it shows up to 10 fields.

For one field of it,  can I get a value from another service/SQL table by customizing application.

I tried to customize it in Visual Studio, but the solution didn't support due to HTTP/HTTPS errors.

For example actual popup window as "ID1" field from "table1" and by customizing I want to change it like:

```
SELECT ID2 FROM table2 WHERE ID1='@ID1'"
```

Get the "ID2" value from "table2" and display it in popup when opened instead of displaying "ID1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using WAB, I guess you have a WebMap.
Then you can customize the Popup directly in your WebMap using Arcade and get information from a related table using a custom attribute expression.

[Here general info about customizing your Popup using arcade](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/data-management/pump-up-your-pop-ups-with-arcade-and-the-living-atlas/)

[Here you have info about getting info from another layers](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-12773-using-featuresetby-functions-in-arcade-to-drill-down-to-other-layers-and-tables)

You're attribute expression would be something like this:

```
// first read out the ID of the Feature1
var id = $feature["ID1"];
// access the table Feature2
var tbl = FeatureSetByName($map, 'Feature2');
// create a sql expression to query on ID
var sql = "ID1 = '" + ID + "'";
// filter the table using the sql expression
var related_data = Filter(tbl, sql);
// count the resulting records
var cnt = Count(related_data);

// initiate a variable to hold the result
var result = 0;

// check if there are related records found for the current ID
if (cnt == 1) {
   // loop through related records
   for (var row in related_data) {
       // read the ID2 from the related data
       result = row.ID2;
   }
} else {
   result = "Not possible to get related records";
}
// return the result
return result;
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you're looking for, but I have been able to customize popups from the underlying web map (as opposed to from within the web app builder).

I think you should be able to configured popups from each layer's drop-down menu.

Comment: i'm trying to show one layer values in other layer popup by performing query

Comment: Oohh, I get it now. Would it work to do a virtual join on that attribute and then label it? I'm not as familiar with processing on Arc as I am on QGIS but that would be my first thought.